# sql/coldfusion select rows with duplicate field

Tags: sql, coldfusion

Here is my table

```
ProductID     Display       UPC
10            0             0553
14            0             0753
11            1             0753
17            1             0453
```

If you notice, row 2 and 3 have the same UPC. I would like to select all rows that have display = 0 and upc to be the same as a row where the display = 1. So in my table I want to select row 2 only. Here is my coldfusion code so far that doesn't work. Please advice.

```
<cfquery name="GetData" datasource="#Application.ds#" dbtype="ODBC" username="#Application.UserName#" password="#Application.Password#">
Select ProductID, Display, UPC
From Products
Where Display = 0
...
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the right query? I'd say there is more than one way to achieve that goal. For me, this one does the job on your example and mysql:

```
SELECT 
  p1.ProductID, p1.Display, p1.UPC
FROM
  Products as p1, Products as p2
WHERE
  p1.UPC=p2.UPC and p1.Display=0 and p2.Display=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using exists(select 1...) is more efficient than a sub-select or join when all you are using it for is a filter.

```
<cfquery name="GetData" datasource="#Application.ds#" dbtype="ODBC" username="#Application.UserName#" password="#Application.Password#">
select ProductID, Display, UPC
from Products p
where Display = 0
and exists (
    select 1 from Products p2
    where p.UPC = p2.UPC
    and p2.Display = 1
)
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer should work or go for the subselect option

```
<cfquery name="GetData" datasource="#Application.ds#" dbtype="ODBC" username="#Application.UserName#" password="#Application.Password#">
Select t1.ProductID, t1.Display, t1.UPC
From Products t1
Where t1.Display = 0 and
      t1.UPC = (Select t2.UPC 
                  From Products t2
                 Where t2.Display = 1)             
</cfquery>
```